# setlistadapter not working in on postexecute

Tags: android

I want an asynchronus task in my dynamic created listview but it gives me error

here is my code

```
public class TenderViewActivity extends ListActivity {  

ArrayList<Spanned> tenders;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Downloaditems dw_tender=new Downloaditems();
dw_tender.execute();        
}//onCreate

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class Downloaditems extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Spanned>, ArrayList<Spanned>, ArrayList<Spanned>> {

@Override
protected ArrayList<Spanned> doInBackground(ArrayList<Spanned>... params) {

Intent intent = getIntent();
cat = intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE4);
tender_name = intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);
title=intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE5);
setTitle(title);

ArrayList<Spanned> tender_res=tenderlist(cat,tender_name);
return tender_res;  
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Spanned> result) {
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>this,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,tenders));

tenders=result;
}   
}
```

This line **setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapterthis,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,tenders));** inside onpostexecute method gives me error like

**The constructor ArrayAdapter(TenderViewActivity.Downloaditems, int, int, ArrayList) is undefined**

pls help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,tenders));
```

to

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(TenderViewActivity.this,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,result));
```

In your case `this` does not refer to  activity context.

Also instead of `tenders` use `result` as the last param. Also add @Override annotation

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Spanned> result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

at

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>this,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,tenders));
```

rather than this use `TenderViewActivity.this`